# Update customer billing address within custom pane

Tags: commerce

I am writing a custom CheckoutPaneBase within Commerce 2 that incorporates shipping and billing information. My goal would be to update the customer's billing address, that is stored as billing profile, programmatically. I looked at the billing information Pane and see that they use:

```
  $billing_profile = $this->order->getBillingProfile();
      if (!$billing_profile) {
        $billing_profile = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('profile')->create([
          'type' => 'customer',
          'uid' => 0,
        ]);
      }
      $billing_profile->populateFromProfile($payment_method_profile, ['data']);
      $billing_profile->save();
      $this->order->setBillingProfile($billing_profile);
```

But rather that populate from $payment_method_profile, I would like to add my own fields' values. I am not sure how I can populate an array to push to populateFromProfile or setBillingProfile or the field values.

Any help or hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the field value like this:

```
  $cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
  $cart = $cart_provider->getCart('default');
  $billing_profile = $cart->getBillingProfile();
  $billing_profile->field_name->value = 'Hello World';
  $billing_profile->save();
```